# Filtering list of list values in R without using for

Tags: r, list, apply, lapply, sapply

I am translating looping `for()` operations into `apply()` family ones: (`sapply`, `lapply`, `mapply`, etc.) to gain performance in all my R code. I have a list of lists named `lt` with the following look:

```
lt

$`11141550000`
            y
2016-02-05 18
2016-03-03  8
2016-03-30  6
2016-04-26  0

$`11140780000`
           y
2016-03-25 2
2016-03-30 0
2016-04-04 0
2016-04-09 0
2016-04-14 0

$`11141550000`
            y
2016-02-05 18
2016-03-03  8
2016-07-16 10
2016-08-12 10
```

One chunk of my code is extremely slow (I know `for` operations are not efficient in R and should be avoided if you want to become more pro in this language). I coded before a chunk like this:

```
for (i in 1:length(lt)){
  lt[[i]] <- lt[[i]][as.Date(index(lt[[i]]), format = "%Y-%m-%d") < "2018-11-01"]
}
```

I am trying to translate this `for` into a fast `Filter` or `sapply`, `lapply` operation, where every value of each list must be before the date `"2018-11-01"`. Nevertheless, I have not been capable of:

#### 1st attempt:

```
f <- function(i){
  lt[[i]][as.Date(index(lt[[i]]), format = "%Y-%m-%d") < "2018-11-01"]
}
lapply(lt, function(x) f(x))
```

But received error:

```
 Error in lt[[i]] : recursive indexing failed at level 2
```

#### 2nd attempt:

```
f <- function(i){
  lt[[i]][as.Date(index(lt[[i]]), format = "%Y-%m-%d") < "2018-11-01"]
}
Filter(function(x) f, lt)
```

But I received this message:

```
Error in Filter(function(x) f, lt) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'logical'
```

#### 3rd Attempt:

```
Filter(f, lt)
```

But again, I received an error:

```
Error in lt[[i]] : recursive indexing failed at level 2
```

I would appreciate any help in translating this `for` operation, as I need understanding better the dynamic of `apply` functions.

#### P.D.1.

Thanks to J.Gourlay feedback I am adding a sample of my list with `dput`:

```
> dput(lt)
structure(list(`11140780000` = structure(c(2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1
), .Dim = c(132L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "y"), index = structure(c(1458864000, 
1459296000, 1459728000, 1460160000, 1460592000, 1461024000, 1461456000, 
1461888000, 1462320000, 1462752000, 1463184000, 1463616000, 1464048000, 
1464480000, 1464912000, 1465344000, 1465776000, 1466208000, 1466640000, 
1467072000, 1467504000, 1467936000, 1468368000, 1468800000, 1469232000, 
1469664000, 1470096000, 1470528000, 1470960000, 1471392000, 1471824000, 
1472256000, 1472688000, 1473120000, 1473552000, 1473984000, 1474416000, 
1474848000, 1475280000, 1475712000, 1476144000, 1476576000, 1477008000, 
1477440000, 1477872000, 1478304000, 1478736000, 1479168000, 1479600000, 
1480032000, 1480464000, 1480896000, 1481328000, 1481760000, 1482192000, 
1482624000, 1483056000, 1483142400, 1483574400, 1484006400, 1484438400, 
1484870400, 1485302400, 1485734400, 1486166400, 1486598400, 1487030400, 
1487462400, 1487894400, 1488326400, 1488758400, 1489190400, 1489622400, 
1490054400, 1490486400, 1490918400, 1491350400, 1491782400, 1492214400, 
1492646400, 1493078400, 1493510400, 1493942400, 1494374400, 1494806400, 
1495238400, 1495670400, 1496102400, 1496534400, 1496966400, 1497398400, 
1497830400, 1498262400, 1498694400, 1499126400, 1499558400, 1499990400, 
1500422400, 1500854400, 1501286400, 1501718400, 1502150400, 1502582400, 
1503014400, 1503446400, 1503878400, 1504310400, 1504742400, 1505174400, 
1505606400, 1506038400, 1506470400, 1506902400, 1507334400, 1507766400, 
1508198400, 1508630400, 1509062400, 1509494400, 1509926400, 1510358400, 
1510790400, 1511222400, 1511654400, 1512086400, 1512518400, 1512950400, 
1513382400, 1513814400, 1514246400, 1514678400, 1514764800), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .indexCLASS = "Date", .indexTZ = "UTC", tclass = "Date", tzone = "UTC", class = c("xts", 
"zoo")), `11141550000` = structure(c(18, 8, 6, 0, 4, 8, 10, 10, 
0, 23, 0, 8, 0, 2, 14, 16, 20, 4, 4, 4), .indexCLASS = "Date", .indexTZ = "UTC", tclass = "Date", tzone = "UTC", class = c("xts", 
"zoo"), index = structure(c(1454630400, 1456963200, 1459296000, 
1461628800, 1463961600, 1466294400, 1468627200, 1470960000, 1473292800, 
1475625600, 1477958400, 1480291200, 1482624000, 1483142400, 1483833600, 
1486166400, 1488499200, 1490832000, 1493164800, 1495497600), tzone = "UTC", tclass = "Date"), .Dim = c(20L, 
1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "y"))), .Names = c("11140780000", 
"11141550000"))
```

#### P.D.2.

As per suggestion of Jozef, I confirm that I have used library `zoo` to reproduce my code. I.e. function `index` of `zoo` package in the `for` loop.

Comment: Can you give us a sample of your data using `dput` ?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @J.Gourlay, as it is a Gigantic list of elements, I have selected only 2 of them in "lt" and applied "dput". I have edited the question thanks to your feedback.

Comment: It would also be nice to specify you are using the package `zoo` to construct your objects.

Comment: Hi @Jozef, I have checked my script and yes, I have used "zoo" library to generate my objects. I will specify that in my question as well thanks to your feedback. Thanks!.

Comment: `apply` functions will just hide the loop, but the loop will still be there. Using vectorised functions may provide a performance improvement but using `apply` probably won't. Look at the function code: there is actually a `for` loop in it!

Comment: Your `for` loop only runs **one** iteration as `i in length(lt)` should be `i in 1:length(lt)` and correcting this may receive same error as *apply* attempts. Always check outputs even if no errors occur!

Comment: I'm not very familiar with `zoo`, but I'm getting dates that probably aren't what you want. For example, `as.Date(index(lt[[1]][1]), format = "%Y-%m-%d")` gets `"3996203-12-21"`. I'm guessing that's not a format you want?

Comment: @Parfait, thanks for your valuable contribution. Changed it in original question. Indeed, it was "i in 1:length(lt)". Did not receive the same error as the apply attempts, but the perfect list I required with each element before specified Date. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, you are passing an object that expects an integer index in your `lapply`. Consider wrapping *lt* in `seq_along(lt)` for the input of `lapply`. Also, remember unlike `for` loops, *apply* functions return objects. So assign `lapply` to an object. Also, when function accepts one non-optional argument, there is no need for specifying the `function` operator.

```
f <- function(i){
  lt[[i]][as.Date(index(lt[[i]]), format = "%Y-%m-%d") < "2018-11-01"]
}

new_lt <- lapply(seq_along(lt), f)
```

If your `for` loop works as you say, *new_lt* should be exactly the same as *lt* after running `for` loop:

```
all.equal(lt_after_for_loop, new_lt)
# [1] TRUE

identical(lt_after_for_loop, new_lt)
# [1] TRUE
```

Alternatively, pass whole objects instead of using indexing with adjusted defined function:

```
f <- function(obj){
  obj[as.Date(index(obj), format = "%Y-%m-%d") < "2018-11-01"]
}

new_lt <- lapply(lt, f)
```

Finally, `Filter()` works to filter (keep or remove) a list's object by logical condition, not the contents within each item of list unless you are using such inner contents to decide the top level item to be removed from list. But `for` and `lapply` does not exclude items during processing (i.e., same number of items before/after their calls).